# How to categorize timestamp hours into day and night?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-analysis

I was wondering how can we categorize timestamp column in a Data frame into Day and Night column on the basis of time?

I am trying to do so but unable to make a new column complete with the same number of entries.

```
d_call["time"] = d_call["timestamp"].apply(lambda x: x.time())

d_call["time"].head(1)
 0    17:10:52
 Name: time, dtype: object

def day_night(name):

    for i in name:

        if i.hour > 17: 
             return "night"

        else:
            return "day"

 day_night(d_call["time"])
 'day'

d_call["Day / Night"]= d_call["time"].apply(lambda x: day_night(x))
```

I want to get the entire series of the column but getting the first index only.

Comment: Please format your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry! I am trying to make a new["day/night"] column on the basis of timestamp column ["time"].
So if time is greater than 1900 I want that entry to be as night in the new columns ["day / night "].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip time to get the hour of timestamp and w.r.t hour you can assign your category, you can also use other conditions to put range of time

```
Considered df
0   2018-06-18 15:05:52.246
1   2018-05-24 21:44:07.903
2   2018-06-06 21:00:19.635
3   2018-05-24 21:44:37.883
4   2018-05-30 11:19:36.546
5   2018-05-25 11:16:07.969
6   2018-05-24 21:43:35.077
7   2018-06-07 18:39:00.258
Name: modified_at, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df['day/night'] = df.modified_at.apply(lambda x:'night'  if int(x.strftime('%H')) >19 else 'day')
```

Out:

```
0      day
1    night
2    night
3    night
4      day
5      day
6    night
7      day
Name: modified_at, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.